# Referencing Multiple File Paths using $ref in Swagger

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, openapi

How can I reference multiple file paths using the **$ref** keyword when documenting my APIs?

What I currently have is this:

```
paths:
  $ref: "./paths/customers.yaml"
```

What I want is:

```
paths:
  $ref: ["./paths/partner.yaml","./paths/merchants.yaml"]
```

Is there a way out?

Comment: Not sure you can use a file reference? Usually you would reference a component in the same specification

Answer (score 0):

$ref is of type string, see https://swagger.io/specification/

You need to do like so:

```
paths:
  /partner:
    $ref: "./paths/partner.yaml"
  /merchants  
    $ref: "./paths/merchants.yaml"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, your solution works but not applicabe to my current workflow. Your solution would force me to define the paths in the `index.yaml` file which is what I am running away from. I want all routes for partners to be strictly under `partners.yaml` and all routes for merchants to be strictly under `merchants.yaml`. The `index.yaml` file that would be merging them shouldn't have any idea of how they are formed. They should just be merged.  OpenAPI specification workflow isn't nice at all. `$ref` should be allowed to accept an array of file paths.